# How to setup facebook stream api

Tags: php, facebook, api, real-time

I'm currently investigating the possibilities of the facebook (and twitter) streaming api. I read the docs but after doing many google searches I still can't figure out how to get a realtime stream from facebook.

If I know it correctly, facebook let's you subscribe to a stream. When there are new updates facebook does a post request to your callback server and let's you handle that information.

I already found a callback example on the facebook github page. But how do I subscribe to a stream?

And is it possible for one registered facebook app to have multiple users connected to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find sample applications here that show you how to subscribe to a stream. https://github.com/facebook/real-time/tree/master/samples

Yes, you can have multiple users of your one app id.  Be sure to pay attention to the `uid` of each `entry` in the array of data your callback server receives. See the "Change Notifications" section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: any latest changes ?